# Python csv: Split column to columns and then to rows by delimiter

Tags: python, csv

I have a column in a csv file which contains person's details in this format:

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Team  |                                                                                                Members                                                                                                 |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Team 1 | OK-10:Jason:Jones:ID No:00000000:male:my notes                                                                                                                                                         |
| Team 2 | OK-10:Mike:James:ID No:00000001:male:my notes OZ-09:John:Rick:ID No:00000002:male:my notes                                                                                                             |
| Team 3 | OK-08:Michael:Knight:ID No:00000004:male:my notes2 OK-09:Helen:Rick:ID No:00000005:female:my notes3 OZ-10:Jane:James:ID No:00000034:female:my notes23 OK-09:Mary:Jane:ID No:00000023:female:my notes46 |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Actual csv format:

```
"Team", "Members"                                                                                                 
 Team 1, OK-10:Jason:Jones:ID No:00000000:male:my notes                                                                                                                                                         
 Team 2, OK-10:Mike:James:ID No:00000001:male:my notes OZ-09:John:Rick:ID No:00000002:male:my notes                                                                                                             
 Team 3, OK-08:Michael:Knight:ID No:00000004:male:my notes2 OK-09:Helen:Rick:ID No:00000005:female:my notes3 OZ-10:Jane:James:ID No:00000034:female:my notes23 OK-09:Mary:Jane:ID No:00000023:female:my notes46
```

I want to split them in a new csv file like this:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| Team  | Member_Rank | Member_Name | Member_Surname | Member_ID_Method | Member_ID_Num | Member_Gender | Member_Notes |
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| Team1 | OK-10       | Jason       | Jones          | ID No            |      00000000 | male          | my notes     |
| Team2 | OK-10       | Mike        | James          | ID No            |      00000001 | male          | my notes     |
| Team2 | OZ-09       | John        | Rick           | ID No            |      00000002 | male          | my notes     |
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Splitting details:

Split Row Delimiter : `' O&-'` where & can be only `'K'` or `'Z'`

Split Column Delimiter : `':'` ,columns number in new csv file is fixed

(One Team can contain many members, there is no upper limit)

***UPDATE***

By using this code provided by @Adirio I get only the last member from fields with multiple members:

```
import csv
import re


members_split_regex = re.compile(r'(O[KZ]-\d+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)(?= O[KZ]|$)')

with open('test.csv') as input_file, open('output_csv.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    fieldnames = csv_reader.fieldnames.copy()
    fieldnames.remove('Members')
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, extrasaction='ignore', fieldnames=fieldnames + ['Member_Rank', 'Member_Name', 'Member_Surname', 'Member_ID_Method', 'Member_ID_Num', 'Member_Gender', 'Member_Notes'])
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv_reader:
        for member_tuple in members_split_regex.findall(row['Members']):
                member_dict = {}
                (
                    member_dict['Member_Rank'],
                    member_dict['Member_Name'],
                    member_dict['Member_Surname'],
                    member_dict['Member_ID_Method'],
                    member_dict['Member_ID_Num'],
                    member_dict['Member_Gender'],
                    member_dict['Member_Notes']
                ) = member_tuple
                print(row['Members'])
                print(member_tuple)
                member_dict.update(row)
                csv_writer.writerow(member_dict)
```

print results:

> row['Members'] ->
>
> OK-1:name1:sunrmae2:ID No:id1233123:male:note12
>   OK-10:name2:sunrame2:Passport No:asda3243242:female:note2
>   OZ-1:nma3:surname3:Passport No:asd213131:other:note 56
>
> print(member_tuple) ->
>
> ('OZ-1', 'nma3', 'surname3', 'Passport No', 'asd213131', 'other',
>   'note 56')

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198930/discussion-on-question-by-netdev-python-csv-split-column-to-columns-and-then-to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @DeepSpace answer but with a fixed [regex](https://regex101.com/r/p5T9da/5) and new requirements added:

```py
import csv
import re


members_split_regex = re.compile(r'(O[KZ]-\d+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)(?= O[KZ]|$)')

with open('test.csv') as input_file, open('output_csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    fieldnames = csv_reader.fieldnames.copy()
    fieldnames.remove('Members')
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, extrasaction='ignore', fieldnames=fieldnames + ['Member_Rank', 'Member_Name', 'Member_Surname', 'Member_ID_Method', 'Member_ID_Num', 'Member_Gender', 'Member_Notes'])
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv_reader:
        for member_tuple in members_split_regex.findall(row['Members']):
            member_dict = {}
            (
                member_dict['Member_Rank'],
                member_dict['Member_Name'],
                member_dict['Member_Surname'],
                member_dict['Member_ID_Method'],
                member_dict['Member_ID_Num'],
                member_dict['Member_Gender'],
                member_dict['Member_Notes']
            ) = member_tuple
            member_dict.update(row)
            csv_writer.writerow(member_dict)
```

The main difference is that I'm deleting the column from the dictionary so that we can use it to update our new dictionary. This way we do not only copy the "Team" column but any other column that is not "Members". To do so the fieldnames of the reader are also copied, the "Members" item removed, and the new ones added to the fieldnames of the writter.

The used regex doesn't hardcode any field, allows spaces in names and surnames, capital Os in the notes, and ID fields that are not just 8-digit numbers.

Comment: @joumaico ty for downvoting my answer that you asked me to post in revenge for my downvote on your answer that was not valid

Comment: @netdev This solution is based on the accepted one with the new requirement you asked for in a comment.

Comment: @DeepSpace Feel free to include the changes in your answer and I will delete this. It is not my intention to copy your code and call it mine, just wanted to answer his new requirements mentioned in the comments of your answer.

Comment: that works covering all my requirements! But one last question just to understand python better, is it possible to somehow not hardcode all the fieldnames but get the existing ones and add just the new ones? Something like this:
`csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=[ Get_all_existing_fields() , 'Member_Rank', 'Member_Name', 'Member_Surname', 'Member_ID_Method', 'Member_ID_Num', 'Member_Gender', 'Member_Notes'])`

Comment: @netdev Look at the edited answer, it also makes this automatic

Comment: I get this error members = row['Members'] KeyError: 'Members'

Comment: Fixed, you need to make a copy of the `csv_reader.fieldnames` as it will use it later to create the rows so we can't remove `"Members"` before iterating. We could remove it after the loop but making a copy is safer.

Comment: I tested with the edited code but now whenever there is more than one member in a row it just gets the last one.

Comment: I cleaned up the code but it should be working properly.

Comment: I get this error `ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Members'`

Comment: Oh yes I forgot the ignore extra fields argument, check now (I also converted it in a single `with`)

Comment: Again the same :( if I print member_tuple just before `member_dict.update(row)` it contains only the last member of a field with multiple members

Comment: Please check my question, I added your code and print results

Comment: Yes `member_tuple` has just the info of one of them, but we write it to the file with `csv_writer.writerow(...)` before we update it with the next member info, thats what the `for` loop is doing.

Comment: I agree but `member_tuple` is in the for loop like print so it should be printed 3 times, one for each member. Right? Sorry I am really noob in python...

Comment: Yes but you are printing `row['Members`]` each loop to so you will have row members, member tuple 1, row members, members tuple 2, row members, member tuple 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198936/discussion-between-adirio-and-netdev).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this input CSV

```
Team,Members
Team 1,OK-10:Jason:Jones:ID No:00000000:male:my notes
Team 2,OK-10:Mike:James:ID No:00000001:male:my notes OZ-09:John:Rick:ID No:00000002:male:my notes
Team 3,OK-08:Michael:Knight:ID No:00000004:male:my notes2 OK-09:Helen:Rick:ID No:00000005:female:my notes3 OZ-10:Jane:James:ID No:00000034:female:my notes23 OK-09:Mary:Jane:ID No:00000023:female:my notes46
```

This can be achieved with regex, [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
import csv
import re

output = []

members_split_regex = re.compile(r'(O[KZ]-\d+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)(?= O[KZ]|$)')

with open('test.csv') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in csv_reader:
        team = row['Team']
        members = row['Members']
        split_members = members_split_regex.findall(members)
        for member in split_members:
                (member_rank, member_name, member_surname, member_id_method,
                 member_id_num, member_gender, member_notes) = member

                output.append({'Team': team, 'Member_Rank': member_rank, 'Member_Name': member_name,
                               'Member_Surname': member_surname, 'Member_ID_Method': member_id_method,
                               'Member_ID_Num': member_id_num, 'Member_Gender': member_gender,
                               'Member_Notes': member_notes})

with open('output_csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['Team', 'Member_Rank', 'Member_Name', 'Member_Surname', 'Member_ID_Method', 'Member_ID_Num', 'Member_Gender', 'Member_Notes'])
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(output)
```

Output file is

```
Team,Member_Rank,Member_Name,Member_Surname,Member_ID_Method,Member_ID_Num,Member_Gender,Member_Notes
Team 1,OK-10,Jason,Jones,ID No,00000000,male,my notes
Team 2,OK-10,Mike,James,ID No,00000001,male,my notes 
Team 2,OZ-09,John,Rick,ID No,00000002,male,my notes
Team 3,OK-08,Michael,Knight,ID No,00000004,male,my notes2 
Team 3,OK-09,Helen,Rick,ID No,00000005,female,my notes3 
Team 3,OZ-10,Jane,James,ID No,00000034,female,my notes23 
Team 3,OK-09,Mary,Jane,ID No,00000023,female,my notes46
```

Comment: Can I suggest `(O[KZ]-\d+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+?)(?= O[KZ]|$)`?

Comment: @Adirio Why would you? it's more complex and the current regex gets the job done

Comment: @DeepSpace 'ID No' is not fixed it can be for example 'Passport No'

Comment: You are hard codding `ID No`, forcing the ID to be a 8-digit number which in case the previous field is not `ID No` may not be even a number, not accepting spaces in names and surnames (compound names are very usual), not allowing a `O` character in the notes column, etc.

Comment: @netdev use his solution but with my regex inside the `re.compile(r'...')` and you should get the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @Adirio yeap it worked with your regex and DeepSpace's solution :)

Comment: @DeepSpace because there are more fields that I just need to copy them in the appended rows is it possible to do it without copying them manually one by one (like the `Team` field)

Comment: There is one `?` spare, the `+?` nearlly at the end could be changed to just `+`: `(O[KZ]-\d+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+):([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)(?= O[KZ]|$)`

Comment: @joumaico I didnt want to copy paste his solution that already did everything the OP requested just swapping the regex. He added one new requirement so I did add an answer but it is still hard based on this answer